# Android XML <intent-filter> - Is there a way to add a NULL mimeType attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

To eliminate the need to have multiple **intent-filters** in a single **Activity's** definition, just to cover the possibility of a mime type not being set, I was wondering if it's possible to add a null attribute to a filter e.g.

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<data><android:mimeType /></data>
OR
<data><android:mimeType xsi:nil="true"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></data>
```

to indicate no mime type entry is ALSO a valid option (the XML above parses but doesn't work). Is this possible and if so what is the correct syntax? As it would save having to create multiple filters e.g.

```
<activity>
    ...
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: You may want to re-think your design.  If I understand this correctly, you are building an Activity that will respond to either (a) data of type "text/html", or (b) data of an unknown type (i.e. no mime-type).  Logically I am not sure that makes sense.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and i'm not totally of my trolly, ran into the issue creating a two dozen line debug [toy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020738/avd-tool-app-to-monitor-or-debug-intent-calls), if you exclude the 300 line manifest.